# Nginx location is redirecting to main proxy_pass

Tags: php, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx to reverse proxy my incoming requests into my docker containers running on local bound ports (e.g. 127.0.0.1:23123).

My following script got a problem:

```
server {
    server_name me-and-my-problem.sample.zone;

    location ~* ^/admin/ {
        rewrite ^/admin/(.*) /$1 break;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:30024;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:30023;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
}
```

Any traffic on the path admin/ should be redirected to my phpmyadmin container. Anything else to my app container but currently, the 404 message of my app container will be thrown.

Comment: I think the phpmyadmin runs on different container. if you are using compose then change `http://127.0.0.1:30024` to `http://YOUR_Service_NAME:30024`

Comment: Nginx is running on my host system, anything else is running in docker containers...

Comment: It seems nginx `location` declaration should be made with correct order. Have you try to move the `location ~* ^/admin/` to the bottom of `location /`?

Comment: No, it doesnt change anything. I currently think about the regex: probably its wrong but I cannot find the mistake :(

Comment: Finally, the regex expression is completely wrong and will be skipped by nginx. Removing the ^ fixed it for me. I also added (.*)$ behind.